# Counting spanning trees that satisfy a condition.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Given a graph, I can count the number of spanning trees of the graph in polynomial time with [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem). Now, I have a graph where each edge has a color. There are exactly $3$ edges of each color (and the total number of edges is a multiple of $3$). Now, if I select an edge of a given color, the other two edges of that color should necessarily be excluded from the tree. How do I count the number of spanning trees of the graph that satisfy this condition?

Comment: That is, it is required to count those spanning trees that contain no more than one edge of each color. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The motivation is a Tesseract where each physical edge becomes three graph edges (if the 2-d faces are vertices).